# Line in front of dots in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have made a bar chart/line chart in d3.js v5 and I have an issue I can't get my head around. The line is running over the top of the dots which is disrupting the tooltip and doesn't look very nice.

[image]

My question is, how do I get the dots to be on top on the line.

Here is the full working example [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/lucasj01uk/q1xr095t/)

Code sample

```
    // line chart dots
bar.append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'dot')
  .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
    return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2; // / 2 links dots over center of bar bandwidth
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .on('mouseover', mouseover)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove1)// Line chart tooltip
  .on('mouseleave', mouseleave);

// line chart
const line = d3.line()
  .x(function (d, i) {
    return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;  // / 2 links line over center of bar bandwidth
  })
  .y(function (d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

bar.append('path')
  .attr('class', 'line')
  .attr('d', line(dataset));
```

I have tried using z-index in the CSS and directly in the JS but I can't get either to work. I also tried moving the dot code above the line code which didn't work.

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: There is no z-index in SVG, the visibility of the elements is determined by the drawing order. Have a look at the section *"SVG, the drawing order"* in this answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39157451/5768908

Comment: I have moved the code that draws the dots to be the last thing that's drawn but it only fixes the last dot https://jsfiddle.net/lucasj01uk/q1xr095t/8/

Comment: Ah, ok, I changed bar.append('circle') on this fiddle right at the bottom!. https://jsfiddle.net/lucasj01uk/q1xr095t/9/ Cheers Mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove

```
bar.append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'dot')
  .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
    return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2; // / 2 links dots over center of bar bandwidth
  })
  .attr('cy', function (d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .attr('r', 10)
  .on('mouseover', mouseover)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove1)// Line chart tooltip
  .on('mouseleave', mouseleave);
```

add

```
g.selectAll('dot')
  .data(dataset)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'dot')  
  .attr('cx', function (d, i) {return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2})  
  .attr('cy', function (d, i) {return yScale(d[1])})
  .attr('r', 5)  
  .on('mouseover', mouseover)
  .on('mousemove', mousemove1)// Line chart tooltip
  .on('mouseleave', mouseleave);
```

And place down at the bottom of the page.

see [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucasj01uk/q1xr095t/9)